# Is PA interpretable in PRA + TI(<epsilon_0)?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

By Gentzen's consistency proof, we know that PA has the same *consistency strength* as PRA + TI(<epsilon_0). Question: is PA *interpretable* in PRA + TI(<epsilon_0)?

For simplicity, let us assume that PRA + TI(<epsilon_0) is formulated as a first-order theory in the language of arithmetic. Then my question is: does there exist a syntactic translation that carries theorems of PA to theorems of PRA + TI(<epsilon_0) by giving definitions of the universe, functions, and relations?

Comment: I can't write a proper answer now, but the answer is yes: PRA + TI($<\epsilon_0$) proves the consistency of each finite fragment of PA, and any r.e. theory $T$ is interpretable in $Q+\{\mathrm{Con}_{T\restriction n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: (I assume you mean by TI the transfinite induction schema for primitive recursive predicates; if you take the schema for all formulas, it trivially contains PA.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! And yes, that is what I meant by TI.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the second part of your answer: "any r.e. theory $T$ is interpretable in $Q + \{\text{Con}_{T \upharpoonright n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$"?

Comment: This is the interpretation existence lemma. It goes back to Wang and Feferman; with PA as a base theory, it is essentially a formalization of the Henkin completeness proof in arithmetic. In order to make it work over $Q$, you use cut shortening in place of induction axioms. I’m not sure what is a good reference for the simple version I quoted; a detailed treatment of a generalized version of the Lemma is in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-63334-3_5 . ($Q+\{\mathrm{Con}_{T\restriction n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is, essentially, $\mho_{*,\infty}(T)$ in §4.3.)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.